# Windowsエクスプローラのプロパティ拡張について

Tags: windows

WindowsエクスプローラでDWGファイルを右クリックしてプロパティウィンドウを表示した時、
AutoCADと同じように「ファイルの概要」を追加し、表示・編集させることはできますか?

Answer (score 2):

Windowsでは[Property System](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/windows-properties-system)が定義されています。
ですので、DWGファイルに対する[Property Handler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/building-property-handlers)を実装し、[レジストリに登録](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/prophand-reg-dist)することができます。これが行われていればExplorerは自動的に「ファイルの概要」を表示し、編集機能を提供します。